# Android Client sends Objects to server and server does receive them but client can't read response

Tags: android, sockets, client

I am sending a Collection(NetworkObject) via ObjectInput and Outputstreams to a server and he receives them without a problem, but he can't read the response which should be a string(also object now for testing). But the app keeps telling me the socket is closed.
Thanks in advance.

My whole Activity

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.example.cl.BasicActivity;
import com.example.cl.data.NetworkObject;
import com.example.cl.R;
import com.example.cl.data.Produkt;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

public class ServerHandler extends BasicActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final int SERVERPORT = 26000;
    public static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.2";
    //public static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.0.206";


    private ClientThread clientThread;
    private Thread thread;
    private LinearLayout msgList;
    private Handler handler;
    private int clientTextColor;
    private EditText edMessage;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect);

        setTitle("Client");
        clientTextColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.green);
        handler = new Handler();
        msgList = findViewById(R.id.msgList);
        edMessage = findViewById(R.id.edMessage);
    }

    public TextView createLine(String message, int color) {
        if (null == message || message.trim().isEmpty()) {
            message = "<Empty Message>";
        }
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setTextColor(color);
        tv.setText(message );
        tv.setTextSize(20);
        tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 0);
        return tv;
    }

    public void showMessage(final String message, final int color) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                msgList.addView(createLine(message, color));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view.getId() == R.id.connect_server) {
            msgList.removeAllViews();
            showMessage("Connecting to Server...", clientTextColor);
            clientThread = new ClientThread();
            thread = new Thread(clientThread);
            thread.start();
            return;
        }

        if (view.getId() == R.id.send_data) {
            String clientMessage = edMessage.getText().toString().trim();
            showMessage(clientMessage, Color.BLUE);
            if (null != clientThread) {
                clientThread.sendMessage(clientMessage);
            }
        }

        if (view.getId() == R.id.send_elem) {

            if (null != clientThread) {
                clientThread.sendElem(/*bestellung*/);
            }
        }
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        private Socket socket;
        //private BufferedReader input;
        private ObjectInputStream ois;

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
                //sleep(250);


                if (socket != null)
                    showMessage("Connected to Server!", clientTextColor);


                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                    //this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
                    //ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
                    //String message = input.readLine();

                    NetworkObject networkObject = (NetworkObject) ois.readObject();

                    /*
                    if (null == message || "Disconnect".contentEquals(message)) {

                        Thread.interrupted();
                        message = "Server Disconnected.";
                        showMessage(message, Color.RED);
                        break;

                    }

                     */

                    showMessage("Server: " + networkObject, clientTextColor);
                    // showMessage("Server: " + message, clientTextColor);
                }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        void sendMessage(final String message) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try(ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));) {
                        if (null != socket) {

                            oos.writeUTF(message);
                            oos.flush();

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

        void sendElem(/*NetworkObject networkObject*/) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try(ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));) {

                        if (null != socket) {

                            Produkt produkt = new Produkt("Bier","Zipfer",16,3.50,1,true);

                            List<Object> produktList = new LinkedList<>();
                            produktList.add(produkt);
                            produktList.add(produkt);

                            NetworkObject networkObject = new NetworkObject("order",46020849,1,produktList);

                            showMessage(networkObject.toString(), Color.BLUE);

                            oos.writeObject(networkObject);

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (null != clientThread) {
            clientThread.sendMessage("Disconnect");
            clientThread = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The thread in the Clienthandler which should read it also contains the sending methods but they should work.

```
private Socket socket;
        //private BufferedReader input;
        private ObjectInputStream ois;

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
                //sleep(250);


                if (socket != null)
                    showMessage("Connected to Server!", clientTextColor);


                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                    //this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
                    //ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
                    //String message = input.readLine();

                    NetworkObject networkObject = (NetworkObject) ois.readObject();

                    /*
                    if (null == message || "Disconnect".contentEquals(message)) {

                        Thread.interrupted();
                        message = "Server Disconnected.";
                        showMessage(message, Color.RED);
                        break;

                    }

                     */

                    showMessage("Server: " + networkObject, clientTextColor);
                    // showMessage("Server: " + message, clientTextColor);
                }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

The error I get

```
W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:119)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:176)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:144)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:248)
W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:288)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:347)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2454)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2470)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2947)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:858)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:353)
        at com.example.cl.serverKom.ServerHandler$ClientThread.run(ServerHandler.java:131)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Comment: `I am sending a Collection(NetworkObject) via ObjectInput and Outputstreams to a server ` No. There is nothing in your code that sends anything.

Comment: Did you really check my code? The first code section contains the whole activity which contains the send methods.But I think you don't even need them because as I mentioned I can send without a problem. And please try to sound a bit more polite.

Comment: I only saw the second block where you start a client. This client does not send anything. It immediately starts to read. I see now that in your first code block you started a client that indeed sents something. Don't expect that your second client can read the messages that were sent to the first client.

Comment: The second part is inside the first but i don't understand why it can't read that's the problem. It keeps telling me that the socket is closed but I don't know why it closes..

Comment: I told you that you should not create a second client socket.

Comment: Could you show me where I am creating a second one, I think I am only using one?

Comment: `socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);` You have that twice.

Comment: You mean in the second and the first code parts?